# find() is not returning an int value that can be used and is giving an error before compiling

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm attempting to get the index value of a new vector created, but the find() function won't let me assign a variable with the returned value of said find()

I have tried to assign the value in other places, fiddle with the beginning and end points, but the program simply won't assign tempind with the value of find().

```cpp
void count_city(vector<string> city, vector<string> state) {
    vector<string> cities(4);
    vector<int> counted(4);
    string temp = " ";
    int tempind = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < city.size(); i++) {
        temp = city.at(i);
        if (find(cities.begin(), cities.end(), temp) != cities.end()) {
            continue;
        }

        else {
            cities.push_back(temp);
        }

        tempind = (find(cities.begin(), cities.end(), temp));
        counted.at(tempind) = count(city.begin(), city.end(), temp);
    }
}
```

I simply want tempind to be the index of the city in the vector cities, however it won't let me compile and gives me an error stating that my type is not the same.

Comment: Your use of `counted` makes no sense, and is very likely to go out of bounds. Also, to avoid storing duplicates, you should consider using a `set<string>` instead of a `vector<string>` for `cities`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::find()` returns an iterator, not an index.  If you need an index, you can pass the iterator to `std::distance()`:

```
auto found = find(cities.begin(), cities.end(), temp);
tempind = distance(cities.begin(), found);
```

But in this case, you don't really need to `find()` the index at all. Since `push_back()` inserts at the end of the vector, the index you want is the size of the vector before you `push_back()` into it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < city.size(); i++) {
    temp = city[i];
    if (find(cities.begin(), cities.end(), temp) != cities.end()) {
        continue;
    }

    tempind = cities.size();
    cities.push_back(temp);

    counted.at(tempind) = count(city.begin(), city.end(), temp);
}
```

Comment: While this works in terms of syntax, the counted.at(tempind) = count(city.begin(), city.end(), temp); gives me an error of out of range. Is that due to my program itself?

Comment: You get the error because you really are going out of bounds. You have 4 elements in both `cities` and `counted` initially (why?). As soon as `cities` has 4+ elements in it, `tempind` goes out of bounds of `counted`.  That is why I commented that your use of `counted` makes no sense at all. What is it trying to accomplish exactly? If you want to count how many times a given city appears in the `city` vector, a `map<string, int>` makes more sense than a `vector<int>`.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I figured it out just as I saw the comment. You're a lifesaver, and I appreciate the help.